# Increase the numbers in cells with comma-separated and sequence wise using drag functionality in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence

I wanna list prepare in excel in which to increase the numbers in cells with comma-separated and sequence wise using drag functionality.

I have used CONCATENATE and other formulas but they are not working.

See the image below, when I drag cell with two rows the output is not coming as the desired result

[image]

Desired Result

[image]

If there any workaround please help me.

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: By '1,2', do you mean 1.2 or 1 and 2?

Comment: @SimpleBinary its comma - 1,2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further details from where these numbers come from, you could add the following formula to `AT2`:

```
=(ROW()-2)*2+1&","&ROW()*2-2
```

Drag down.

Comment: Numbers are statics and due to large set I wanna look around it accordingly